# Wordpress website login issue after laptop shutdown

Tags: wordpress

[wordpress browser screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWh24.png)
I am a beginner with wordpress.
I just created a website locally on my laptop. The default page of 'Hello World' also came up.

But then i 'Shut down' my machine. When i started my laptop again, i am unable to view the 'localhost' website created.

The url i am trying is -
http://localhost/wordpress/

I have installed xampp inside -C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress
My xampp control panel is running and Apache and MySQL module services are running.

Am i missing some setting? Can anyone please help?

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Please attach a screen short. What showing on the browser ?

Comment: I think your xampp server would be stoped after shutdown laptop. You have to start xampp server and the go to that link.

Comment: And for login to wordpress go to http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin.

Comment: Hello everyone, Thanks for the reply. I am attaching the screen shot that i am getting. Kindly note that my xampp server is running.

Comment: Please find the link for my browser screen shot in question itself.

Comment: @WisdmLabs - My Xampp server is running as shown in my attached screen shot.

Comment: Click on the "config" button beside Apache and then click on "Apache httpd-config" then look for "8080" to replace with only "80" and be sure that skype is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows Apache is listening on ports 4443 and 8080, but the url in your address bar is http://localhost/wordpress. Since that URL does not specify a port the default 80 will be assumed. Try http://localhost:8080/wordpress instead.

Comment: Hello misterben,
Thanks for your reply.
In that case why was the url not coming as 
http://localhost:8080/wordpress
when i had installed and had not restarted my laptop.

I am sure that the url that got created after my installation was 
http://localhost/wordpress

Ravi